# What is the correct way of using context managers to read files?

Tags: python, contextmanager

I'm wondering about the correct way of using context managers in Python for reading in files with additional logic that's dependent on the loaded in file - from a memory management and overall best practice perspective which of the below is better and why?

```
with open(my_file, "r") as fp:
   file_contents = fp.read().splitlines()
   for content in file_contents:
      print(content)
```

or

```
file_contents = []
with open(my_file, "r") as fp:
   file_contents = fp.read().splitlines()
for content in file_contents:
    print(content)
```

Comment: Why not just iterate over the file directly?

Comment: `for line in fp:`

Comment: Unless you expect to have another process waiting for the file to be released, it does not *really* matter

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica probably not relevant in this case, but using the second example allows to release the file early (for example, if another process might wait for it)

Comment: NVM I completely missed the `file_contents = fp.read().splitlines()` in the first example.

Comment: Essentially the question really is, is it better to exit the context manager as soon as possible if additional logic is dependent on the loaded in contents?

Comment: In short - yes. Why would you want to hold the file open if you know you're not going to use it anymore?

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on my comments:

Memory wise both are the same.

However, the first example keeps the file open for longer (while reading **and** iterating), while the second one keeps the file open only while reading.

It might make a difference for very long files **and** if there is another process that waits to read or write to the file, otherwise the difference is neglectable.

Best-practice wise, I'd go with the second approach. If we can close the file early, we might as well do it.